# List as a constraint variable in a Haskell type signature?

Tags: haskell

Rather than declaring this type-signature:

```hs
g :: Enum a => [a] -> [a]
```

I'd like to use this style:

```hs
h :: (Enum a, Functor f) => f a -> f a
```

except to swap `Functor` out with `[]`. (e.g. because I might be happy to be less general in my implementation for the time-being).

Although I'd like to, I can't use the following,

```hs
i :: (Enum a, [] f) => f a -> f a 
-- compilation error: Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘f’ has kind ‘*’
```

since the `[] f` is probably interpreted as a list of `f`, rather than `f` being interpreted as a constraint-variable for a list of something.

The following works, but I'd like to know if it is possible to declare a List as an actual constraint-variable in a Haskell type-signature.

```hs
j :: (Enum a) => [] a -> [] a
```

Answer (score 8):

`[]` is not a constraint and it never will be. In Haskell, every type has a *kind*, which is kind of like a type of type. It's one level up.

Things like `[Int]`, `String`, and `Double -> Double` are concrete types. We say they have kind `Type`. Something like `[]` or `Maybe` has kind `Type -> Type`; it takes a type as argument and then produces a type itself.

On the other hand, something like `Functor` is fundamentally different. `Functor` has kind

```
Functor :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
```

So, first off, it takes a parameterized type, like `[]` or `Maybe` as argument. But even once it does so, it produces a `Constraint`, a fundamentally different thing than a `Type`. Now, when we write a type signature

```
j :: (Enum a) => [] a -> [] a
```

The things on the left of the `=>` are *always* constraints and the thing on the right of the `=>` is *always* a `Type`. It makes no more sense to put `[] a` on the left-hand side of `=>` than it does to put `Functor a` on the right-hand side.

It sounds like the thing you're trying to express is "this thing has to be a list", in which case either of the following will suffice

```
j :: (Enum a) => [a] -> [a]
j :: (Enum a) => [] a -> [] a
```

the two are equivalent but the former is *much* more idiomatic. If you come along later and decide "oh wait, I can make this work for any functor, you can change the type signature to

```
j :: (Enum a, Functor f) => f a -> f a
```

And this won't break any of the code that's calling `j`, as any code that was calling it with a list before will still be calling it with a valid `Functor` instance.

---

Note: You'll see some old literature that refers to the kind `*`. Some literature (and even GHC in some places) will say that `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`. For these purposes, `*` is equivalent to `Type`. Being able to refer to `Type` as `*` is an unfortunate historical quirk and complicates the Haskell parser (is `Foo * Int` equivalent to `Foo Type Int` or is it multiplication like `(*) Foo Int`?), so the general recommendation nowadays is to use `Type` to refer to the kind of types.

Comment: thank you. Could we always say: (i) the kind of classes (e.g. Enum, Functor) is ...Constraint; (ii) the kind of types (e.g. Maybe, []) is ...Type?

Comment: Yes, typeclasses will define `Constraint` instances and data declarations will define `Type` instances. There is also a third kind, `#`, but you won't encounter it often. `#` refers to unboxed types used deep down in the compiler, whereas `Type` refers to the ordinary Haskell types we use everyday. So, for example, `Int#` is a lot closer to what C would call an `int`, whereas Haskell's `Int` is a Haskell datatype with all of the benefits that come with that

Comment: @RonRamsay Strictly speaking type classes are always things that can be applied (to one type-level object, or more if using `MultiParamTypeClasses`) to *result* in a thing of kind `Constraint`. e.g. `Eq` is not of kind `Constraint`, it's of kind `Type -> Constraint`, while `Functor` is of kind `(Type -> Type) -> Constraint`. However the thing to the left of the `=>` has to be a `Constraint` (or a tuple of them), which usually means a *fully applied* type class (a type equality constraint `T ~ S` is another option for something with kind `Constraint` as mentioned in HTNW's answer).

Answer (score 8):

You can declare equality constraints as

```
g :: (Enum a, [] ~ f) => f a -> f a
```

under suitable language extensions. Read the operator `(~)` as equality or congruence.

- Either set one of `-XGADTs` or `-XTypeFamilies` at the GHC command line.
- Or, place either

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
  ```

  at the top of the file.

Is it really worth it, though?

Comment: It's really equality and not congruence in GHC Haskell.

Comment: @dfeuer I just meant that the symbol `~` resembles the mathematical symbol for congruence.

Comment: True. I think it's unfortunate that we don't have something that looks more like `=` there.

Comment: @HTNW To answer your question, I suspect in most cases it wouldn't be worth it. I'll investigate those extensions. Thank you.